# Merge ApplicationDbContext with my custom DbContext

Tags: entity-framework

I need to merge my ApplicationDbContext with my DemoPoolEntities context.  What do I need to do to to properly merge the two? The reason I need to do this is so that I can access the `ApplicationUser` data from the `Customer` class which is a part of the `DemoPoolEntities` context. I am not sure where to start to merge these two so they are both in one `DbContext`.

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace DemoPool.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DemoPoolEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

**DemoPoolEntities**

```
namespace DemoPool.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

    public partial class DemoPoolEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DemoPoolEntities()
            : base("name=DemoPoolEntities")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Kit> Kits { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Type> Types { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Condition>()
                .Property(e => e.Condition1)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.CompanyName)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.FirstName)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.LastName)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.PhoneNumber)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.Email)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.Address1)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.Address2)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.City)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.State)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.Zip)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Kit>()
                .Property(e => e.KitName)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Loan>()
                .Property(e => e.TrackingNumber)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .Property(e => e.ProductName)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .Property(e => e.Description)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .Property(e => e.ProductNumber)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .Property(e => e.SerialNumber)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .Property(e => e.Manufacturer)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Type>()
                .Property(e => e.Type1)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
                .HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
                .HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DemoPoolEntities` need to inherit from `ApplicationDbContext`

```
public partial class DemoPoolEntities : ApplicationDbContext
{
   ...
}
```